# Trouble extending/inheriting generics with typescript

Tags: inheritance, typescript-generics, type-safety

I'm having trouble combining generics with interface extensions in typescript. My basic use case is this:

1. Base interface
2. Child interfaces that extend from parent interface (only 1 level deep inheritance)
3. Each child interface contains data not in the base interface
4. Some fields may or may not be shared between the various sibling interfaces

I want to be able to write a type-safe generic function that can correctly recognize the child interfaces generically, including matching arguments to the generic interface appropriately.

I have been successful in using discriminators for the extended interfaces, but am having trouble tying it out to the other arguments. For example:

Here is our base type, along with a discriminator value "Type":

```
interface Base<T> {
    type: T
    a: string
    b: number
}
```

Here are the possible extensions / inheritors:

```
type ExtensionType = 'CDate' | 'DBool' | 'CString'

interface ExtensionCDate<T = 'CDate'> extends Base<T> {
    c: Date
}

interface ExtensionDBool<T = 'DBool'> extends Base<T> {
    d: boolean
}

interface ExtensionCString<T = 'CString'> extends Base<T> {
    c: string
}
```

The idea here is that ExtensionCDate can only take on the generic value of 'CDate', and thus it's type value is always 'CDate', etc.

Here is how I am attempting to solve this problem:

1. Use a union type of the possible child interfaces:

```
type GenericExtension<T extends ExtensionType> = ExtensionCDate | ExtensionDBool | ExtensionCString
```

2. Generate a corresponding interface to each child interface that includes only the fields present in the child interface that are NOT present in the base interface (set difference essentially):

```
type ExtendedData<T extends ExtensionType> = Omit<GenericExtension<T>, keyof Base<T>>
```

3. Write a function that uses discrimination to correctly deal with each possible child:

```
const genericFunc = <T extends ExtensionType>(obj: GenericExtension<T>, data: ExtendedData<T>): void => {
    switch ( obj.type ) {
        case 'CDate':
            obj.c = data.c  // data.c should exist
            return
        case 'DBool':
            obj.d = data.d  // data.d should exist
            return 
        case 'CString':
            obj.c = data.c  // data.c should exist
            return
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, while the typing for obj seems to work, the discriminator doesn't also apply to the data parameter. I know I could use casting (data.c as ExcludedData<'CDate'>), but I see that has a hacky solution and not ideal.

The error I am getting is the following:

```
TS2339: Property 'c' does not exist on type 'Pick  , never>'.
```

Which makes me think I am at the very least doing the ExtendedData type incorrectly.
I feel like the solution should be fairly straightforward. What am I missing here?

Thanks! Let me know if I can provide any additional context to help come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3):

There's some confusion here between the generic, which depends on a variable subtype `T`, and the instances of specific subtypes.

```
type GenericExtension<T extends ExtensionType> = ExtensionCDate | ExtensionDBool | ExtensionCString
```

In the above line, you've declared a generic `T` but haven't actually used `T` in your type definition.

```
interface ExtensionCDate<T = 'CDate'> extends Base<T> {
    c: Date
}
```

In the specific extensions, what you've actually done with `<T = 'CDate'>` is set the string literal `CDate` as the **default value** for `T` if `T` is not set, but it actually can still be set to any value because we haven't imposed any limits on it.

What you want is for your specific extension types to no longer take a generic `T` variable.  Instead we manually set the `T` for the `Base<T>`.

```
interface ExtensionCDate extends Base<'CDate'> {
    c: Date
}

interface ExtensionDBool extends Base<'DBool'> {
    d: boolean
}

interface ExtensionCString extends Base<'CString'> {
    c: string
}
```

Since our `GenericExtension` isn't actually "generic" in the typescript sense, let's call it `AnyExtension` instead.  This type is the union of the three specific extension types.

```
type AnyExtension = ExtensionCDate | ExtensionDBool | ExtensionCString
```

We can actually derive the union of the three type strings from this rather than writing it out.

```
type ExtensionType = AnyExtension['type'] // evaluates to type "CDate" | "DBool" | "CString"
```

We are still going to run in to some problems with the `switch` statement because switching based on `obj.type` refines typescript's knowledge of the type of `obj` but **not of T**.  Even though you know that if `obj.type === "CDate"` that `T` must also be `"CDate"`, typescript doesn't make this leap and therefore will *not* refine its knowledge of the type of `data` based on the `switch`.

Unfortunately I think you do need some sort of `as` assertion, at least on the `data` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've since given up on getting this to work and ended up taking a different route. It's unfortunate typescript doesn't allow this to work cleanly!